# Meteor SSL protect specific page

Tags: ssl, meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to SSL protect specific page only (like /checkout) in meteor?

I know I can setup http proxy but that would mean I have to protect all the pages.

I am using iron-route for routing.

Example Pages:

/home - no SSL

/products - no SSL

/about - no SSL

/checkout - with SSL

/admin - with SSL

/contact-us - no SSL

Comment: Why would you want not to provide SSL for the whole page when you're configuring it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is the normal HTTP but inside an SSL connection. Because the SSL is done first and then later it gets from the HTTP which page you access, it is not possible to protect only specific pages of a web site. There are several ways to do something similar:

- use a different domain for the secure part and protect the complete domain with HTTPS
- allow but not enforce everything with HTTPS, but if a sensitive page gets accessed with plain HTTP throw an error or redirect the user to the HTTPS page. Note that this redirect can be problematic with posted content, e.g. forms - but you should anyway always protect already the form itself and not only the form submission.